# calculate image screen occupy percentage

Tags: html, image, css

Lets say I have `<img>` tag. I can get width and height of the image like

```
width = 150px height=200px
```

But I want how much of the screen does the image occupies? I have a table with width 100%.This table contains there columns 
First column I have a fixed logo of 5%.

Second column I have a anchor tag.Third column I have image whose width and height varies on every row .

Now I need to set the second column anchor tag such that the text should automatically shrink or expand based on the image in third column.

Suppose image width is 60%. Now 2nd column width should be 35% (i.e 100% -60% - 5% )
So how to calculate how much percentage does image width occupies **(Not Pixels)**

I appreciate your help

Comment: CSS3's [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function

Comment: Or JavaScript. Or maybe `display: table`.

Comment: Or a maxwidth on the iamge? Say `img {max-width: 60%}` ?

Comment: @LcLk I see most of browsers doesn't support calc() and in that case i need to fix the width of image to support fallback which is what i want to avoid

Comment: I would agree that most old browsers don't, but those which do are almost [80% of the market](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Only cross-browser solution would be JS. And be weary using percentage sizes with images, they may appear blurry, especially on mobile browsers.

Comment: unfortunately my client always use that 20% of the browsers market.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the width of an image you can use .width().

For example:

```
imageWidth = $("img.imageClass").width();
```

With that said, in order to calculate the width in percentage you need to know the width of the widest image.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    widestImg = 0;
    $("img.imageClass").each(function(){
        w = $(this).width();
        if (w > widestImg) { 
          widestImg = w;
        }
    });
});
```

The calculation for the largest image has to run in a window load function because all images need to load for an accurate assessment.

Now you can get your percentage by simply dividing

```
percentage = $("img.imageClass").width() / widestImg;
```

Add an alert to get the numbers to assist you.

```
alert(percentage);
```

Comment: Hey I don't want to get average or widest/largest image. I just want to know how much percentage of the screen does the image can occupy. Hope you are clear about my point

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` of the column or cell that you want to be dynamic to `100%`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pbqz6jg/)